# Sortable big table

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a table with 30000 rows and I want to be sortable with clicking on the column name. I can do this by JavaScript for small tables but it takes a long time for a big table. Do you have any suggestion how I can solve this problem?

I have this code but is so slow:

```
function sortTable(n, m) {
  var table, table2, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementsByClassName('myTable')[m];
  switching = true;
  //Set the sorting direction to ascending:
  dir = "asc";
  /*Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done:*/
  while (switching) {
    //start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    rows = table.rows;
    /*Loop through all table rows (except the
    first, which contains table headers):*/
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      //start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
      one from current row and one from the next:*/
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      /*check if the two rows should switch place,
      based on the direction, asc or desc:*/
      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch= true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }

    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark that a switch has been done:*/
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      //Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
      switchcount ++;
    } else {
      /*If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
      set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again.*/
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you may use [datatables with a remote data source](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html)

Comment: So, are you showing a HTML table with 30.000 rows in a single page? Do you want to keep that approach? Sorry, but the question as it currently is written, is just too broad

Comment: @Alfabravo Yes. It's a packet trace. I want to show them in a single HTML Page. If there is another way, I am so interested to do.

Comment: We can't tell you how to improve the performance of your code until you share your code with us. Please edit your question to include the code you've written so far.

Comment: @JordanRunning I added.